# How to increase GNOME timed wallpaper repaint frequency?

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop, wallpaper

I'm setting up a timed wallpaper in GNOME, but when `duration` is configured to be < 1 second, it doesn't work as expected.

The `duration` (or each frame) is timed correctly, however the desktop wallpaper itself is only actually being painted once per second.

Would it be possible to configure GNOME / Debian to repaint the desktop more frequently? The target is 60 updates per second, but getting it to 30, 15, or even 2 updates per second would be progress at least.

###### What I've tried:

1. Looking for solutions online, but they tend to set the `duration` > 1 second, or use additional software to play videos or GIFs on the desktop. I'm keen to get the best results I can without additional software.
2. Read the documentation, but GNOME doesn't have much for timed wallpapers, just normal wallpapers, which isn't helpful. ([Desktop Wallpaper](https://help.gnome.org/users/gthumb/stable/gthumb-desktop-wallpaper.html.en), [Add extra backgrounds](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/backgrounds-extra.html.en))
3. I have been unable to find a generic setting related to the wallpaper or desktop update frequency.

###### My Files

###### `~/Pictures/W6cMZ6wfCjk/live-wallpaper.xml`

```xml
<background>
  <static>
    <duration>0.016666667</duration>
    <file>/home/redacted/Pictures/W6cMZ6wfCjk/frames/001.png</file>
  </static>
  <static>
    <duration>0.016666667</duration>
    <file>/home/redacted/Pictures/W6cMZ6wfCjk/frames/002.png</file>
  </static>

  <!-- … 581 frames in total, spaced 0.016666667 seconds apart so 60 fps -->
```

###### `~/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/live-wallpaper.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">
<wallpapers>
 <wallpaper deleted="false">
   <name>Redacted Wallpaper</name>
   <filename>/home/redacted/Pictures/W6cMZ6wfCjk/live-wallpaper.xml</filename>
   <options>zoom</options>
 </wallpaper>
</wallpapers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's feasible but changing your wallpaper 60 times a second is going to peg your CPU, a better solution would be for Gnome Shell to natively support animated backgrounds from a video stream.

Anyhow, here's how to proceed:

```
# Create a folder to hold your custom overlays
mkdir -p .gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui
echo 'export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/shell=$HOME/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays"' \
   >> .profile

# Extract the file we want to customize
gresource extract /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so /org/gnome/shell/ui/background.js \
    > ~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui/background.js

# Change the minimum frame time (feel free to adjust)
sed -i 's:ANIMATION_MIN_WAKEUP_INTERVAL = 1.0;:ANIMATION_MIN_WAKEUP_INTERVAL = 1/60;:' \
    ~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui/background.js
```

Then logout from your session and log back in again.